# error al seleccionar factura en c# con stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

estoy tratando de generar una factura individual por paciente, entonces con el stored procedure que cree, me esta llamando el paciente, pero todas sus facturas, y lo que necesito es una individual.

ayuda por favor.

aqui parte de lo que tengo.

Codigo SP

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_SF](
  @idc int
  )
  as
  select * from Facturas where IdCliente = @idc
```

Foto de lo que me muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en mi proyecto, esta es una factura individual de ese dia, y cuando le doy a imprimir ahi me muestra todas las demas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muestra final de factura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El procedimiento almacenado está ejecutando correctamente lo que tu le dices. El problema es que tu quieres que haga otra cosa.

La estás pidiendo que te dé las facturas de un cliente (`@idc` corresponde al identificador de cliente)

Cuando lo que le deberías pasar es el `id` de la factura

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_SF](
  @idFactura int
  )
  as
  select * from Facturas where Id = @idFactura
```

Si no tienes a mano el `id` de la factura y siempre querrás obtener la última factura de ese cliente, lo que deberías hacer es

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_SF](
  @idc int
  )
  as
  select top 1 * 
  from Facturas 
  where IdCliente = @idc
  Order by Fecha Desc
```